# JavaScript: filter object entries by key

Tags: javascript, object

how to filter and return key-value pairs if key is not equal to `"targetTime"`. I have tried with:

```js
const obj = {
  "name": "Rima Biswas",
  "email": "rima.biswas@test.com",
  "station": "Agartala",
  "targetTime": { "startDate": "2022-02-01T18:30:00.000Z", "endDate": "2022-02-28T18:30:00.000Z" }
};

const entries = Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => key != "targetTime ");

console.log(entries);
```

Comment: What doesn't work about the filter you've already tried? Are you mapping after the filter?

Comment: You seem to have a typo. `"targetTime "` should likely be `"targetTime"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

```
const requiredData = Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => key !== "targetTime")
```

Or

```
const {targetTime, ...restData} = obj;
const requiredData = restData;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the code below:**

```
   let obj =   {
        "name": "Rima Biswas",
        "email": "rima.biswas@test.com",
        "station": "Agartala",
        "targetTime": {                
            "startDate": "2022-02-01T18:30:00.000Z",
            "endDate": "2022-02-28T18:30:00.000Z"
        }};

  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key]) => key !== 'targetTime'));
```